# Lumia 630 visible on router but not showing on desktop file explorer network group

Tags: 8.1, networking

We have an ASUS RT-AC68U router serving our home network.  The desktop is wired and runs W7HPx64 SP1.  All addresses are manually assigned for my convenience.  The Lumia 630 OS is W8.10.14234.0.  Our problem is that the Lumia is visible on the router on 2.4GHz (we don't see a need for 5GHz) but File Explorer on the desktop does not see the phone.  Compounding the frustration is that there appears no way for the Lumia to show the desktop.  We do have the "Folders" app from BitApp Studio, but that is not helping at the moment.  A possibly related annoyance is that we cannot even ping the phone from the desktop if the display has timed out.

Is there something we should know about networking with the Lumia?

Comment: What do you mean by having the "Lumia show the desktop"?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Windows Phone 8.1 does not support Windows file sharing. The "Workstation" and "Server" services, which enable this functionality, are not present. Therefore, it will not show up over the network in Explorer on a PC. You can install apps (such as Metro File Manager) that support acting as a Windows Networking *client* in place of the Workstation service - that is, they can connect to another computer to push or request files - but I'm not aware of any app on the phone that lets it act as a file sharing server (although theoretically one could be built).

For browsing the files on a Windows phone from a PC, use USB to connect the phone to the PC. Alternatively, use an FTP server app (although unless the phone is jailbroken, such an app will not be able to see much).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had suspected this might be the case, after all phones are for speech and text and taking pictures, not for working things out. So USB is the (obvious) way to go, and it works just fine. If I could see how to mark this as the (preferred) answer, I'd do it. Oh, I **am** the person (gordon451) who asked the original question. While I'm here, I did try to address Rowland Shaw's query, but I don't have creds to add a comment, and my edit to clarify the point was disallowed by the moderators.

Comment: If both are your accounts you can merge them. See here for details - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist

Comment: @SomeBloke Your edit was rejected because you used a different username than for the original post, so there was no way to know that you were the same person. You should log in with your original account, then you can edit and comment on your question directly, as well as mark answers as accepted, or you can follow the advice above to get the two accounts merged.